# ERROR: PleskFatalException: StatInfo->getActiveDomainsNumber() failed: sysinfo failed: sh: /usr/local/psa/admin/bin/sysinfo: Permission denied

Tags: php, linux, bash, plesk

I ran this command `/usr/local/psa/admin/bin/mail_auth_view` but this was displaying none. I surf the net and found that this `/usr/local/psa/admin/sbin/mchk --without-spam` command can repair it but plesk become more worst.

I tried `/usr/local/psa/admin/sbin/mchk --with-spam
 1004  ==> Checking for: mail_imap_restore... fail
 1005  ==> Checking for: mail_spam_restore... fail`

`/etc/init.d/psa start` but seeing following error:

> ERROR: PleskFatalException: StatInfo->getActiveDomainsNumber() failed:
>   sysinfo failed: sh: /usr/local/psa/admin/bin/sysinfo: Permission
>   denied
>
> Additionally, an exception has occurred while trying to report this
>   error: PleskFatalException StatInfo->getProductVersion failed:
>   sysinfo failed: sh: /usr/local/psa/admin/bin/sysinfo: Permission
>   denied (class.SystemStatisticsForm.php:123)

Search for related Knowledge Base articles`

Please advise

Answer (score 0):

Check files:

```
# ls -la /usr/local/psa/admin/bin/sysinfo
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 15 Apr  7  2015 /usr/local/psa/admin/bin/sysinfo -> ../sbin/wrapper
# ls -la /usr/local/psa/admin/sbin/sysinfo
-rwxr-x---. 1 root root 72920 Aug 11  2014 /usr/local/psa/admin/sbin/sysinfo
```

Pay attention that `/usr/local/psa/admin/bin/sysinfo` it is a symlink to `../sbin/wrapper`

wrapper file:

```
 # ls -lZ /usr/local/psa/admin/sbin/wrapper
 ---s--x---. root psaadm system_u:object_r:bin_t:s0       /usr/local/psa/admin/sbin/wrapper
 # ls -lnZ /usr/local/psa/admin/sbin/wrapper
 ---s--x---. 0 501 system_u:object_r:bin_t:s0       /usr/local/psa/admin/sbin/wrapper
 # file /usr/local/psa/admin/sbin/wrapper
 /usr/local/psa/admin/sbin/wrapper: setuid ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.18, stripped
 # lsattr /usr/local/psa/admin/sbin/wrapper
 -------------e- /usr/local/psa/admin/sbin/wrapper
```

If you on a RedHat-like OS, for a test, you can temporary switch off Selinux by:

```
# setenforce 0
# getenforce
Permissive
```

Comment: what relationship Selinux has with sbin/wrapper?

Comment: Selinux context I believe `ls -lZ /usr/local/psa/admin/sbin/wrapper` https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Security-Enhanced_Linux/chap-Security-Enhanced_Linux-SELinux_Contexts.html

Comment: Thanks for clarification but problem still exists. No changes at all

Comment: So, the permission on sysinfo and wrapper files are also well?